# Google smart home touch control for device-type "blinds"

Tags: google-smart-home

I want to get touch control for device type "blinds". Since it is not available for device type "Blinds". I tried to use "blinds" as device type to have "blinds" as display icon and gave "on/off" trait instead of "open/close" to have on/off touch control which does not work.

Is there any way I can have touch control for Blinds?

Answer (score 0):

Ohh trust me i have this gripe with how slow google is with their smart home stuff. If you want any UI for your object, unfortunately you have to pick one from https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/touch-controls

In your case, I'd make it a 'switch' or 'outlet' with OnOff trait.

On a side note, Alexa is even worse somehow because they don't even have a blind object (or anything to do with open/close).